# esp8266 - server.handleClient() fails to call assigned function

Tags: esp8266, wifi, nodemcu, esp8266webserver

I'm trying to get one esp to send integers to a second as a part of a simple remote control, but after multiple days I can't get it to work. The transmitter seems like it's connecting and sending properly as best I can tell, and the receiver is sending some kind of response, but the function I attached with server.on() never gets called.

The code is basically copy and pasted from a tutorial, the only thing I changed was removing code to display the read data to an LCD and display to serial instead.

This is the receiver's code.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>



const char *ssid = "controllerReceiver";
const char *password = "password";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();

  server.on("/data/", HTTP_GET, handleSentVar);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("server online");
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();

}

void handleSentVar() {
  Serial.println("Handling");
  if (server.hasArg("x_value")) { // this is the variable sent from the client
    int readingInt = server.arg("x_value").toInt();
    Serial.println(readingInt);
    server.send(200, "text/html", "Data received");
  }

}
```

And here is the transmitter

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>



const char *ssid = "controllerReceiver";
const char *password = "password";

int outputValue = 999;        

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  // Explicitly set the ESP8266 to be a WiFi-client
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("connecting...");
    delay(500);
  }

}

void loop() {

  char intToPrint[5];
  itoa(outputValue, intToPrint, 10); //integer to string conversion for OLED library

  // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
  WiFiClient client;
  const char * host = "192.168.4.1";
  const int httpPort = 80;

  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");

    return;
  }

  // We now create a URI for the request. Something like /data/?sensor_reading=123
  String url = "/data/";
  url += "x_value=";
  url += intToPrint;

  // This will send the request to the server
  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  unsigned long timeout = millis();
  while (client.available() == 0) {
    if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
      Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");

      client.stop();
      return;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Running a whole webserver + client is waaay overkill for a remote control. Use UDP packets instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace "/data/" with "/data" and `url += "x_value="` with `url += "?x_value="`.

The HTTP GET parameters are separated from the *path* by "?". The `on` function is executed for *a path* ("/data").

Comment: If you sub `server.on("/data/"`, don't you need the trailing slash in the request also? some web hosts tack that on for you, but the ESP doesn't.

Comment: @dandavis, no..

Comment: I just tested it by `on()`ing `/test` and `/test/` with different functions, and they are indeed discrete. This is why there's repetitive stuff like `server.on("/read/", getReading);  server.on("/read", getReading);` in my old sketches. I now use a macro that subs both the plain and slashed path to make it easier and would have been pleased+surprised to find out it was useless. Maybe async server is different...